# What field should I use when collecting external system user info in SF Marketing Cloud?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I've been wondering which field should I use when collecting user purchases, views, etc. There are a couple of different resources in Salesforce about this and both of them tell differently.

First one is under Email Recommendations -> Implementation, inside marketing cloud itself:
[image]
And it says that Subscriber Key should be used.

The other one is from Salesforce Docs (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ctc_set_user_info.htm&type=5):
[image]
This one says that Subscriber ID should be used.

As far as I understand it, these two are completely different. **I use Contact Id from Salesforce as my SubscriberKey** and I think Subscriber Id is generated inside marketing cloud itself.

The JSON itself has a field that's named "email" - the name suggests that email should be used.